# Laravel - orWhere causes wrong results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have the following query

```
 Event::where('event_name', $event_id)
        ->orWhere('id', $event_id)->first();
```

The **$event_id** can be a alpha-numeric string (event_name) or an integer (id - primary key). The orWhere statement takes priority over the where statement everytime unless the orWhere statement fails.

For example, the following query gets an event with id = 601, eventhough there is an event that has an `event_name = 601a35e0ebee30` with id = 1070.

```
 Event::where('event_name', "601a35e0ebee30")
        ->orWhere('id', "601a35e0ebee30")->first();
```

1. Shouldn't the where statement take precedence over orWhere? Am I missing something?
2. Also how come a alpha-numeric string work with the primary key (id) which is an unsigened integer?

**P.S.** When I use `Event::find("601a35e0ebee30")`, it returns an event with id of 601

Comment: "The orWhere statement takes priority over the where statement everytime unless the orWhere statement fails." I don't think it does, it takes the first record that matches one of the 2 conditions. If you change the order, the other Event will be returned. the priority for where and orWhere is equal

Answer (score 0):

use nested array
Event::where([['event_name', $event_id]])->orWhere([['id', $event_id]])->first();[image: it works for me]

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one.

```
Event::where(function($query) use ($event_id){
   $query->where('event_name', $event_id);
   $query->orWhere('id', $event_id);
})->first();
```

Comment: That does exactly the same thing, but with a unneeded function

Comment: @GertB. its working for me so please try it.

Comment: I did not say the code does not work. But it does exactly the same as the code in the question. with more code.

Comment: quick test : `select * from events where event_name = '601a35e0ebee30' or id = '601a35e0ebee30' limit 1` is the query produced by the code in the question, 

`select * from events where (event_name = '601a35e0ebee30' or id = '601a35e0ebee30') limit 1` from your code